# LinkHandler hook on TYPO3 8

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

Is there any hook to handle links with the new LinkHandler for TYPO3 8.7?

On the old LinkHandler extension is possible to define a hook to process the links as we want.
I need to overwrite the parameter of typolink based on some rules. Is there a way to do this on my extension?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple points to hook into.

**TypoLink post-processing**
You can hook into the TypoLink post-processing to modify the typolink itself before it gets rendered.

For this, you first register your custom class in ext_tables/ext_localconf:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_content.php']['typoLink_PostProc'][] = 'Vendor\\Name\\Service\\TypoLinkProcessingService->postProcessTypoLink';
```

Then, inside your `TypoLinkProcessingService` class (with your name of choice, of course), you'd handle it inside your own method. For visualisation purposes, in this example, I'm altering an URL if it is a link to a youtube video in order to turn off "related videos" at the end, and to modify the color used by the controls inside youtube's player.

```
public function postProcessTypoLink(&$parameters, ContentObjectRenderer &$parentObject)
{
    if (isset($parameters['finalTagParts']['url'])) {
        $urlParts = parse_url($parameters['finalTagParts']['url']);
        if (stristr($urlParts['host'], 'youtube.com') !== false && stristr($urlParts['path'], 'watch') !== false) {
            $parameters['finalTag'] = str_replace(
                '"' . htmlspecialchars($parameters['finalTagParts']['url']) . '"',
                '"' . htmlspecialchars($parameters['finalTagParts']['url'] . '&rel=0&color=ffffff') . '"',
                $parameters['finalTag']
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

**TypoLink UserFunc**
Another option is to utilise `userFunc` and adapt links.

For this, you configure your linkhandler configuration (PageTS) to provide `userFunc` inside `typolink`. Add TypoScript as needed to later fetch the configured data.

```
config.recordLinks {
    tx_myest {
        typolink {
            userFunc = Vendor\Name\UserFunc\TypolinkUserFunc->parseLinkHandlerTypolink
            userFunc {
                newsUid = TEXT
                newsUid.data = field:uid

                newsClass = TEXT
                newsClass.data = parameters:class

                defaultDetailPid = 53
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your `parseLinkHandlerTypolink` method, you can access configured properties and adapt as required:

```
class TypolinkUserFunc
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
     * @inject
     */
    public $cObj;

    /**
     * Add a method description here
     *
     * @param array $content
     * @param array $configuration
     * @return string
     */
    public function parseNewsLinkHandlerTypolink(array $content, array $configuration)
    {
        if (!$configuration['newsUid']) {
             return;
        }

        $params = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($configuration['newsClass'], $configuration['newsClass.']);
        $newsUid = (int)$this->cObj->cObjGetSingle($configuration['newsUid'], $configuration['newsUid.']);

        // ... your code goes here ...

        $url = $this->cObj->typolink('', $typolink);
        return '<a href="' . $url . '" ' . $attributes . '>';
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this hook that has been introduced in 8.6 may also help you: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79121-ImplementHookInTypolinkForModificationOfPageParams.html